# Bootsrap 4: Disable button until modal animation is done

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm using a Bootstrap 4 modal to show a big navigation.
To open the navigation I'm using a toggle button with a CSS animation. The animation changes a hamburger menu icon to an X.

The problem is, that if you click to fast and the modal animation isn't ready, the button gets confused and shows the X even at an already closed menu/modal.

Is there any way to disable the button until the modal animation is ready?

Here's my code:

```
$('.menu').click(function(){
   $('#burger').toggleClass('active');
});
```

I saw, that there is a way to listen to the modal animation:

```
$('#myModal').on('shown', function () {
  // do something… 
})
```

But I could not figure out how to implement it in my function.

Here's my actual code: https://codepen.io/cray_code/pen/JjjqRpN

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just tie toggling of the burger to both show/hide modal events..

```
var toggleBurger = function () {
  $('#burger').toggleClass('active-sandwich');
}

$('#nav-modal').on('show.bs.modal', toggleBurger)
$('#nav-modal').on('hide.bs.modal', toggleBurger)
```

[Demo](https://codeply.com/p/4KYyV7E7QJ)

Comment: Nice, thank you. That works almost perferct. There is still some time where it changes but not that much

Answer (score 1):

Well you could write it like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var isShown = false;
    $('#nav-modal').on('shown.bs.modal', function(){
        isShown = false;
        $("#burger").css("display", "block");
    });

    if(!isShown)
    {
        $('#burger').on('click', function(){
            isShown = true;
            $("#burger").css("display", "none");
        });
    }

    $('#nav-modal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
       isShown = false;
       $("#burger").css("display", "block");
    });
```

Sorry if the code kind of messy, but I hope you could understand what I mean.
basically I only put some boolean to make sure its showing or not.
After that I validate it. If isshown is false then you can't click until isshown true.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand how I add my `.active` class to the button on click?!